# Trying to make an image move whenever clicked, however the .click even only fires the first time clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I'm attempting to have an image (#goon) move and become resized whenever clicked.  The code works great, however it only works the first time it is clicked.  After the first time the image is clicked, clicking the image does noithing.

Here is the Javascript code:

```html
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*  750 + 1)
var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 + 10)

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#goon").click(function move() {
        $("#goon").animate({left: random},0)
        $("#goon").animate({top: random},0)
        $("#goon").animate({height: random2},0)
        $("#goon").animate({width: random2},0)
    })
});
```

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Goon</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type = "text/css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "goondiv">
    <img src = "goon.jpg" id = "goon"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My sincere apologies if this is a silly question, but I am still fairly new to web development.

Comment: Why are you using `.animate`? Why are you repeatedly rebuilding the `$("#goon")` jQuery object no less than 4n+1 times, for n clicks?

Comment: I would start by throwing in a `console.log('test');` in your function to check it's being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your random values are only computed once, at the start of your script. Your element is animated to the exact same values on every click, the effect only shows the first time.

You should create new values on every click instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#goon").click(function move() {

        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*  750 + 1)
        var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 + 10)

        $("#goon").animate({left: random},0)
        $("#goon").animate({top: random},0)
        $("#goon").animate({height: random2},0)
        $("#goon").animate({width: random2},0)
    })
});
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by random position. But if you mean randomly sized square in a random position: 1. Get a random size. 2. Get a random position removing the square size.

Comment: I apologize, you saw my comment before I deleted it.  I got it all figured out.  Once again, thanks a bunch for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id = "goondiv">
    <img src = "goon.jpg" id = "goon"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var random = 750;
var random2 = 200;

$("#goon").click(function move() {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*  750 + 1)
    random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 + 10)
    $("#goon").animate({left: random},0)
    $("#goon").animate({top: random},0)
    $("#goon").animate({height: random2},0)
    $("#goon").animate({width: random2},0)
});
```

**Working Example**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cme370pj/1/)